# OOZIE: properties defined in file referenced in global job-xml not visible in workflow.xml

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I'm new to hadoop and now I'm testing simple workflow with just single sqoop action. It works if I use plain values - not global properties.

My objective was however, to define some global properties in file referenced in `job-xml` tag in global section.

After long fight and reading many articles I still cannot make it work.
I suspect some simple thing is wrong, since I found articles suggesting that this feature works fine.

Hopefully, you can give me a hint.

In short:

1. I have properties, `dbserver`, `dbuser` and `dbpassword` defined in `/user/dm/conf/environment.xml`
2. These properties are referenced in my `/user/dm/jobs/sqoop-test/workflow.xml`
3. At runtime, I receive an `EL_ERROR` saying that `dbserver` variable cannot be resolved

Here are details:

I'm using Cloudera 5.7.1 distribution installed on single node.

`environment.xml` file was uploaded into hdfs into `/user/dm/conf` folder.
Here is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
            <property>
               <name>dbserver</name>
               <value>someserver</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>dbuser</name>
               <value>someuser</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>dbpassword</name>
               <value>somepassword</value>
            </property>    
</configuration>
```

`workflow.xml` file was uploaded into `/user/dm/jobs/sqoop-test-job`. Here is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="sqoop-test">
    <global>
        <job-xml>/user/dm/conf/env.xml</job-xml>
    </global>
    <start to="get-data"/>
    <action name="get-data">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.3">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>       
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${outputRootPath}"/>
            </prepare>
            <arg>import</arg>
            <arg>--connect</arg>
            <arg>jdbc:sqlserver://${dbserver};user=${dbuser};password=${dbpassword}</arg>
            <arg>--query</arg>
            <arg>select col1 from table where $CONDITIONS</arg>
            <arg>--split-by</arg>
            <arg>main_id</arg>
            <arg>--target-dir</arg>
            <arg>${outputRootPath}/table</arg>
            <arg>-m</arg>
            <arg>1</arg>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Sqoop-test failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage()}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

Now, I execute oozie workflow from command line:

```
sudo -u dm oozie job --oozie http://host:11000/oozie -config job-config.xml -run
```

Where my job-config.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>nameNode</name>
        <value>namenode:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>jobTracker</name>
        <value>jobtracker:8021</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>oozie.wf.application.path</name>
        <value>/user/dm/jobs/sqoop-test-job/workflow.xml</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>outputRootPath</name>
        <value>/user/dm/data/sqoop-test</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, you are making two big mistakes.

**1.** Let's start with a quick exegesis of some parts of the Oozie documentation (V4.2)

[Workflow Functional Specification](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html)

- has a section 19 about Global Configuration
- has sections 3.2.x about **core Action types** i.e. MapReduce, Pig, Java, etc.
- the XML schema specification clearly shows the `<global>` element

[Sqoop action **Extension**](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html)

- does not make any mention of Global parameters
- has its own XML schema specification, which evolves at its own pace, and is not up-to-date with the Workflow schema

In other words: **the Sqoop action is a plug-in** as far as the Oozie server is concerned. It does not support 100% of the "newer" functionalities, including the `<global>` thing that was introduced in Workflow schema V0.4

**2.** You don't understand the distinction between *properties* and *parameters* -- and I don't blame you, the Oozie docs are confused and confusing.

*Parameters* are used **by Oozie** to run **text substitutions** in properties, in commands, etc. You define their values as **literals**, either at submission time with the `-config` argument, or in the `<parameters>` element at Workflow level. And by "literal" I mean that you cannot make reference to a parameter in another parameter. The value is just immutable text, used as-is.

*Properties* are **Java properties passed to the jobs** that Oozie starts. You can set them either at submission time with the `-config` argument *-- yes, it's a mess, the Oozie parser has to sort out which params have a well-known property name and which ones are just params --* or in the `<global>` Workflow element *-- but they will not be propagated in all "extensions", as you have discovered the hard way --* or in the `<property>` Action element or **inside an XML file** defined with `<job-xml>` element, either at global Workflow level or at local Action level.

Two things to note:

- when *properties* are defined multiple times with multiple (conflicting) values, there has to be a precedence rule but I'm not too sure
- *properties* defined explicitly inside Oozie may have their value defined dynamically, using *parameters* and EL functions; but *properties* defined inside `<job-xml>` files must be literals because Oozie does not have access to them (it just passes the file content to the Hadoop `Configuration` constructor at run-time)

What does it mean for you? Well, your script tells Oozie to pass "hidden" *properties* to the JVM running the Sqoop job, at run-time, through a `<job-xml>`.
But you were expecting Oozie to parse a list of *parameters* and use them, at compile time, to define some *properties*. That won't happen.

Comment: Hi Samson, thanks a lot for this great explanation :) Now it is more clear to me and btw. your explanation should be in Oozie documentation - just to save time of others :)

Comment: @ArB - actually, the explanation it is still incomplete -- the "properties" passed at submission time are actually Java properties used by the *Oozie server* and not by the user-defined actions; more generally, props prefixed by `oozie.` are used by the server and/or the Oozie library that bootstraps job execution in the YARN container.