# Oozie param tag before the script tag?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Is it possible to use a `<param>` tag in oozie before the `<script>` tag.

Like below:

```
               <param>script_name=${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['SCRIPT_NAME']}</param>
                <script>/tmp/abc/hive/${script_name}</script>
                <param>K_NAME=${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['K_NAME']}</param>
                <param>P_NAME=${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['P_NAME']}</param>
                <param>CNAME=${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['C_NAME']}</param>
```

The reason is my script name should be passed as a paramter and not hardcoded. And this script name is to be taken fron my mysql database like `${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['SCRIPT_NAME']}`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm... any reason you can't write directly `<script>/tmp/abc/hive/${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['SCRIPT_NAME']}</script>`??

Comment: Besides, expression `${script_name}` refers to an Oozie *parameter* (as in `<parameters>` section of Workflow, or in the config file at submit time), not to a local `<param>` that is meant to be passed as-is to the Pig action.

Comment: More details about what is a "parameter" in Oozie dialect, in that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337362/oozie-properties-defined-in-file-referenced-in-global-job-xml-not-visible-in-wo

Comment: haha cool.. didnt think it that way. It works. Thanks  Samson :)

FIX:
`<script>/tmp/abc/hive/${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['SCRIPT_NAME']}</scri‌​pt>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can not do, because Oozie workflow/action xml expects everything in order as defined in the schema.

Also, Your understanding of the `<param>` tag also appears to be wrong. It is not for declaring a variable and using it later on. I am guessing you are writing an `hive` action, `<param>` are used to pass the `<key=value>` parameter to the hive job. This is similar to `--hivevar` for specifying the variables in hive SQL. `key` is a variable you have used in the hive sql script.

You can do as mentioned by the @SamsonScharfrichter:

```
<script>/tmp/abc/hive/${wf:actionData('GetJobParameters')['SCRIPT_NAME']}</scri‌​pt>
```