# global variable HADOOP_USER_NAME oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, sqoop

is there any way that I can declare the HADOOP_USER_NAME as a global variable in a oozie workflow? actually I'm creating several shell actions for my project but it's not efficient to declare a HADOOP_USER_NAME for each shell action that's why I'm wondering if a global variable can take place in this scenario, if so, how can I proceed with it...

Your help is really appreciated.

This is the code I'm using

```
<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
  <global>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>HADOOP_USER_NAME</name>
                <value>*****</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
  </global>
<start to="shell-a0a5"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Error [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="shell-a0a5">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>script1.sh</exec>
        <file>script1.sh#script1.sh</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

for some reason I'm not getting the value from HADOOP_USER_NAME perhaps I'm doing it wrong, I had to write it down into the shell file as export HADOOP_USER_NAME=****;

Comment: The "properties" in your Oozie script are **java properties** that are passed to the Oozie "launcher" class. They are not environment variables!!!

Comment: And anyway, only "core" Oozie actions inherit the global properties. Not the shell/hive/sqoop/spark actions that are actually plug-ins, with their own XML schema. See the first part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337362/oozie-properties-defined-in-file-referenced-in-global-job-xml-not-visible-in-wo/38338713#38338713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `<property>` to any kind of Oozie action that is running a **Java** utility -- but not to a shell action.

In your specific case, you can declare an `<env-var>` locally in *each* shell action, and you can define the actual value of that variable globally...

- in the `<parameter>` section of the workflow
- or in the configuration file at submit time

  <workflow-app name='hello-wf' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <parameters>
      <property>
        <name>hadoopUser</name>
        <value>biloute</value>
      </property>
    </parameters>
  ...
    <action name='some-shell'>
      <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>script1.sh</exec>
        <env-var>HADOOP_USER=NAME=${hadoopUser}</env-var>
        <file>script1.sh#script1.sh</file>
      </shell>
      <ok to="End"/>
      <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
  ...

Answer (score 0):

You could add the global tag on top of the workflow which acts as the global configuration for the actions in that workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="wf-name">
<global>
<job-tracker>${job-tracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${namd-node}</name-node>
<job-xml>job1.xml</job-xml>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
        <value>${queueName}</value>
        <name>HADOOP_USER_NAME</name>
        <value>${username}</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```