# How to create a variable with EL expression to use in all the actions oozie workflow?

Tags: hadoop, el, oozie

I want to create a variable that should be available to all the actions in the Oozie workflow. I have tried to create it as shown below. But EL expression is not getting evaluated resulting in variable current_ts value as EL expression itself. Can somebody please throw some light on this?

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="no-op-wf">
  <parameters>
    <property>
      <name>current_ts</name>
      <value>${replaceAll((replaceAll((replaceAll((timestamp()),"-","")),"T","_")),":","")}</value>
    </property>
  </parameters>
  <start to="test"/>
  <kill name="test">
    <!--message Just to show that this expression works if used here>Timestamp - [${replaceAll((replaceAll((replaceAll((timestamp()),"-","")),"T","_")),":","")}</message-->
    <message>Timestamp - ${current_ts}</message> <!-- this will print expression but not evaluate it -->
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: Could you try using global or configuration tags , So that the property is available across the workflow.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I create a global->configuration->property in workflow and reference it in the other actions of the wf then EL expression in the property will not get evaluated.

As a workaround, I wrapped the wf as a sub wf and created global->configuation->property in parent wf and then passed it to subwf. with this workaround EL expression got evaluated.

Parent WF :

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="main-wf">
  <global>
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>run_ts</name>
        <value>${replaceAll((replaceAll((replaceAll((timestamp()),"-","")),"T","_")),":","")}</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
  </global>

 <action name="tbl-subwf">
    <sub-workflow>
      <app-path>${AppPath}</app-path>
      <propagate-configuration/>
 </sub-workflow>
    <ok to="join-node"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
  </action>
 <kill name="fail">
    <message>Sub workflow failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>
  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: You may find that post useful (section 2) for the difference between *parameters* and *properties*... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337362/oozie-properties-defined-in-file-referenced-in-global-job-xml-not-visible-in-wo/38338713#38338713

Answer (score 0):

In [Parameterization of Workflows](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4_Parameterization_of_Workflows) it's mentioned that :

> EL expressions can be used in the configuration values of action and decision nodes. They can be used in XML attribute values and in XML element and attribute values.

They cannot be used in XML element and attribute names. They cannot be used in the name of a node and they cannot be used within the transition elements of a node.

but you can use it in the coordinator